# Query Activity system error in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

Why am I getting a system error with this Query Activity in Automation Studio?

```
Select 
  o.AccountID
, o.JobID
, o.SubscriberKey
, o.EventDate
, o.isUnique
, o‌​.Domain
, o.Subscriber‌​ID
, o.OYBAccountID
, o.‌​ListID
, o.BatchID,
s.T‌​riggererSendDefiniti‌​onObjectID 
from _Open as o 
where DATEDIFF(hour, o.EventDate, GETDATE()) <= 0
```

Answer (score 11):

Typically if [**Query Activities**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) fail, it's one of these 6 things:

1. **Primary key violation** -- your query results in duplicate rows not allowed by the primary key
2. **Inserting a null value into a non-nullable field**
3. **Inserting a value too long** for the field (truncation)
4. **Timeout** -- if your query doesn't complete within the 30-minute timeout window, it'll error out.
5. **Your target Data Extension no longer exists**
6. **Data type conversion** -- trying to insert a `$12.34` string into a Decimal field

SFMC Support can tell you the exact error from the server log.

I've [**previously written**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/troubleshooting-queries-sfmc/) about my go-to methods for troubleshooting errors like these.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common error when the structure of the target data extension does not match the incoming data.

You can work around this by checking your Text/Date/Number data types, and making all fields NULLABLE.

If you still have problems, double check the source data format matches the Data extension you've made: [**Data View: Open**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_open/)