# SQL query to link email open date & last purchase date / Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, sql

Thank you for your response.
The error message is this one : "   Automation failed due to system error."

Comment: What is the error message? Please **[edit]** your post to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the system error is not helpful ( a support case can provide the actual error), but the typically causes for this are as follows:

- Non Nullable Fields and Null values - Easiest way to troubleshoot is to make fields nullable
- Truncation issue - value to long for field inserting into - Ensure you match field length between source and target
- Primary Key constraint - The query returns multiple values of PK field - Remove any PK field to troubleshoot

Comment: I've found there are about 6 common causes: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169095/query-activity-system-error-in-automation-studio/169145#169145

Comment: The Support from SF gave me that feedback " The issue seems to be to do with the conversion of datetime to date with the statement "CONVERT(date, 'o.OpenTime')"

I would suggest matching the columns data types within each data extension you are joining to resolve this."However, the format of my fields are dates plus the fields that Im mapping are written exactly the same way so Im note sure I understood everything...